# Firestore Query with timestemp in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, nosql, timestamp

I'm building an app where I need to get the list of tasks planned for today. But I'm not sure how to write the query for it.

this is the query I have now which gives a list of tasks from the current time onwards to infinity. but I would want tasks having only today's date.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection('tasks').where(
          'uid', isEqualTo: "$uid").where('time', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: DateTime.now()).snapshots()
```

Comment: Can you show me the date you have placed in the table? the record which has date?

Comment: the date is a time stamp in the collection   

time:May 16, 2019 at 9:00:00 AM UTC-4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need only the documents of a day, you need a query whose bounds are the beginning and the end of the day. In Flutter you can do this as follow:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    DateTime start = now.subtract(Duration(hours: now.hour, minutes: now.minute, seconds: now.second));
    DateTime end = start.add(Duration(days: 1));
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection('tasks').where(
          'uid', isEqualTo: "$uid").where('time', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: start).where('time', isLessThanOrEqualTo: end).snapshots()
```